MS Teams "connectors" - How to setup an AzureDevOps pipeline connection for builds on master/main branch only?
I'd like to get alerts in an MS Teams channel for whenever a software build pipeline completes, but only if it was run on the master/main branch. We're using AzureDevOps pipelines.
In Microsoft Teams this is almost possible using the Connectors functionality:

However the available filters do not include a filter for the branch name, even if you select a particular repository:

This leads to a lot of noise when developers are experimenting with dev branches. Is it possible to filter this connector just to a specific branch?
Perhaps it requires a different Connector that my organisation does not have available?
ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/integrations/microsoft-teams?view=azure-devops
This is a different connector but has the same problem
